# WPF GridView SetReadOnly or Enabled on a column based on a checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a `RadGridView` (telerik's version of a `GridView`) and in this `RadGridView` I have the following column:

```
<telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Revoked}" AutoSelectOnEdit="True" Header="Revoked" UniqueName="Revoked" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="False" FooterTextAlignment="Right" CellStyle="{StaticResource GridCellStyle}" />
```

I want to either enable/disable or set the read only flag on another two columns in the grid based on the checkbox column.

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn 
    DataMemberBinding="{Binding RevokedBy}" 
    Header="Revoked By" 
    UniqueName="RevokedBy" 
    Width="Auto" 
    IsReadOnly="{Binding Revoked}" 
    FooterTextAlignment="Right" 
    CellStyle="{StaticResource GridCellStyle}" />
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn 
    DataMemberBinding="{Binding RevokedDateTime}" 
    DataFormatString="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" 
    Header="Revoked Date Time" 
    UniqueName="RevokedDateTime" 
    Width="Auto" 
    IsReadOnly="{Binding Revoked}" 
    FooterTextAlignment="Right" 
    CellStyle="{StaticResource GridCellStyle}">
   <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <WrapPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4">
               <telerik:RadDateTimePicker 
                   Margin="0 5 5 5" 
                   Width="250"
                   DisplayFormat="Short"                                     
                   InputMode="DatePicker" 
                   DateSelectionMode="Day"
                   DateTimeWatermarkContent="Select Date"
                   MaxWidth="155"
                   MinWidth="155"
                   SelectedDate="{Binding RevokedDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

               <telerik:RadMaskedDateTimeInput 
                   Margin="5"
                   Culture="en-GB"
                   EmptyContent="Enter Time"
                   InputBehavior="Replace"
                   Mask="HH:mm:ss"
                   SelectionOnFocus="SelectAll"
                   TextMode="MaskedText"
                   Value="{Binding RevokedTime, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
           </WrapPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

So far I have tried binding the `IsReadOnly` and `IsEnabled` property to `Revoked` but this doesn't seem to work, and I can see that the `Revoked` property is being set and the `RaisePropertyChanged` event is recurring.

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATED:

**ViewModel:**

```
/// <summary>
/// The agreements.
/// </summary>
private ObservableCollection<NotificationAgreement> agreements;

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the agreements.
/// </summary>
public ObservableCollection<NotificationAgreement> Agreements
{
    get
    {
        return this.agreements ?? (this.agreements = new ObservableCollection<NotificationAgreement>());
    }

    set
    {
        this.agreements = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Agreements);
    }
}
```

And the NotificationAgreement class has the following property.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets a value indicating whether revoked.
/// </summary>
public bool Revoked
{
    get
    {
        return this.revoked;
    }

    set
    {
        this.revoked = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Revoked);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste your ViewModel, I just want to know that your are raising Notification to view when Revoked is Changed.

(1) Your viewmodel should have one `ObservableCollection<yourObject>`

(2) `yourObject` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

(3) your Object should have property in following way

```
private bool _revoked;

public bool Revoked 
{
   get{return _revoked;}
   set { _revoked=value;
         RaisPropertyChanged("Revoked");
}
```

This is just mock code, please do it in your way.

Comment: Updated my question as requested